# Extra items in popup menus on Mac

Tags: popup, menus

On my mac, when I create a popup menu I always get a few extra items tacked on:

Example

```
(defun tab-line-tab-context-menu (&optional event)
  "Pop up the context menu for a tab-line tab."
  (interactive "e")
  (let ((menu (make-sparse-keymap (propertize "Context Menu" 'hide t))))
    (define-key-after menu [close]
      '(menu-item "Close" tab-line-close-tab :help "Close the tab"))
    (define-key-after menu [shiftleft]
      '(menu-item "Shift Left" tab-line-shift-tab-left :help "Shift the tab left"))
    (define-key-after menu [shiftright]
      '(menu-item "Shift Right" tab-line-shift-tab-right :help "Shift the tab right"))
    (define-key-after menu [copypath]
      '(menu-item "Copy Path" tab-copy-current-filename-to-clipboard :help "Copy the current tab filename to the clipboard"))

    (popup-menu menu)))
```

This will create a popup but in addition to the defined items I'm getting two extra items
"Autofill" and "Services" which seem to be some kind of global set of entries. I notice they are there for all the system defined context menus as well

[image]

Does anyone know what controls this behavior? Is it possible to turn it off?

Comment: Which version of macOS?

Comment: Latest Sonoma  version.

Answer (score 1):

Services is a standard macOS feature it appears on every popup menu created using Apple's tools. It is the same as on the main Application menu e.g. the Emacs menu on Emacs.

For example right click on a edit window on StackExchange in Safari and you will see services.

[Apple document on Services](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1012/mac)

> Services let you use features of other apps for the task you’re doing without having to open those apps.

I think the only way to disable the Services menu is by changing the code in Emacs itself.

Comment: That's what I was wondering was the case. Running x-popup-menu also shows this behavior and that's one of the builtin c functions.

I've never done anything with the mac cocoa layer. I wonder how hard that is to tinker with.

Comment: Not hard I think - but it does mean altering the C code in emacs - so not practical.

Comment: As for Autofill I am only on Ventura and I don't see it - whether that is the reason I don't know